# jQuery validate element without form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Working on validation with ASP.Net webforms.

ASP.Net by default adds a form at root level. Which mean we need to add all the controls with in the form only.

However I need to define a small portion of the page which requires validation, I used jQuery validation plugin.

**HTML**

```
 <html>
 <body>
  <form method="post" action="AssetDetails.aspx" id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-
   data">
     //Other page content goes here. which doesnt require validation

    <form class="form-horizontal" id="validation-form" method="get">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="widget-header header-color-blue2">
                                <h5>
                                    Step 1</h5>
                            </div>
          <input type="email" name="ctl00$MainContent$AssetTabs$DefineCriticality$email" id="email" class="span6" />
                        </div>

     </form>
  </form>
  </body></html>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('#validation-form').length); // gives 0, because this form nested under  
                                          another form generated by ASP.Net

  $('#validation-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-inline',
            focusInvalid: false,
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }},
             messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Please provide a valid email.",
                    email: "Please provide a valid email."
                }},
     errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
     }
    });
    });
```

But the problem is, I am getting error `this[0]` is undefined in jquery validation file. I found that `#validation-form` is not found in the DOM, since this form is inside that stupid ASP.Net generated root(parent) element.

How do we handle this?

**Is there a way we validate element using jQuery validate plugin with out a form?**

**Edit: Got some Workaround Solution:**

Finally I made this work with parent form and adding rules based on the field name. Once again ASP.Net webform started giving trouble by generating control name field differently.

Here is the work around code.

```
    var validationParams = {
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-inline',
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {},
        messages: {},

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            $('.alert-error', $('.login-form')).show();
        },

        highlight: function (e) {
            $(e).closest('.control-group').removeClass('info').addClass('error');
        },

        success: function (e) {
            $(e).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('info');
            $(e).remove();
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.insertAfter(element);
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
        },
        invalidHandler: function (form) {
        }
    };

    var emailFieldName = $('#email').attr('name');

    validationParams['rules'][emailFieldName] = { required: true };
    validationParams['messages'][emailFieldName] = { required: "Email is required" };

    $('#Form1').validate(validationParams);
```

***Is there any other better way of doing it?***

Answer (score 1):

I am not telling you other options, but what you asked, if you can use validate plugin without form.

It is absolutely required that you have `<form></form>` tags for the jQuery Validate plugin to function properly, or at all.

If you use `ajax`, you must [put your `ajax` inside the `submitHandler` of the jQuery Validate plugin

You can remove or block the `action` and still use jQuery Validate.

You can put your `ajax` and a `return false` in the `submitHandler` and no regular submission will occur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize plugin
        // your rules & options,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax would go here
            return false;  // blocks regular submit since you have ajax
        }
    });

});
```

---

**See demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/NEPsc/5/**

Comment: The problem is due to parent form, my `#validation-form` is not available. I updated my question. I need a validation with jquery validation plugin, works with out a form :)

Comment: You can simply use $(parent-form).validate(), and use checks(validation) for the elements you require, why are you using a form within form?

Comment: I am not using. This is how ASP.Net stupid webforms designed. We dont have a control of removing that parent form

Comment: Oh sorry then. I haven't used asp yet.:(

Comment: I updated my work around solution. Not sure is that a better way :)